# Setting Graph3D Edge Thickness With Edge Weights

Tags: graphs-and-networks

So I'm very (very, very) new to Mathematica. I have a 3D graph (generated with `Graph3D` from a graph generated by `WeightedAdjacencyGraph`) and I would like to use edge weights from the original, 2D weighted graph to set the thickness of the edges on the 3D graph. I'm aware that I can use `EdgeShapeFunction -> (Tube[#, radius] &)` with some preset radius to make all of the edges have some thickness, but I can't figure out how to (or if it's possible to) make the edges have differing thicknesses.

Comment: I believe I already described everything you need in the link above, both with pure Mathematica and IGraph/M.  You need to set a different `EdgeShapeFunction` for each edge.  Probably the most compact way is with IGraph/M, `IGEdgeMap[
 Function[weight, {CapForm["Rounded"], Tube[#, 0.1 weight]} &],
 EdgeShapeFunction -> IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight],
 g
 ]`

Answer (score 1):

```
myEdges = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1};

myEdgeWeights = {.01, .02, .03};

myAssociation = AssociationThread[Sort /@ myEdges -> myEdgeWeights];

Graph3D[myEdges, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Tube[{First[#1], Last[#1]}, myAssociation@Sort[#2]]} &)]
```

[image]

Comment: What about doing it in 3D?

Comment: The issue is that a) that's 2D, I need to do it in 3D, and b) I can't set the thicknesses manually like that, they need to be automatically extracted from the edge weights (because the edge weights change every time I run my code, it's non-deterministic).

Comment: OK... I'm on it... just a few minutes...